# Add text on top of an image IF image starts with a specific name? | JS Wrapping image in a class

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a set of images on my server that start with a certain name so:

"communityphoto_John.jpg"

"communityphoto_Mary.jpg"
etc.

Would it be possible with PHP to display a text on top of the image whenever it would find these images starting with "communityphoto_"? such as:
"Photo submitted by the community, submit yours to our email"

I've found some solutions but they all seem to bake the text on to the image (like create/save an actual image with the embedded text), but I just wish to display the text over the image, as in the future it might change, but I wouldn't want to have to replace all images.

I apologize in advance that I couldn't be more helpful, I'm still in the beggining of my PHP adventure and haven't gotten so far yet. 
Thank you very much in advance for your attention and advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think JavaScript and some CSS would be a better option for you in this case. Depending on how the images are loaded, your best bet would still be to parse or filter it, and add a class (or some HTML) anyways.

Take the following snippet for example. It finds all the images with `communityphoto_` in the name, and if it finds any, loops through them, wraps them in a `<div>` with the `.community-image` class.

Then with some CSS you can make use of the [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo-class to position some arbitrary text on it however you want. You could also add this text as a `<span>` or something in the JavaScript if you wanted. Also note you can't just do the `::after` on the `img` takes because `img` tags are *void* elements (aka self-closing) that don't take any content under any circumstances, so that's why I wrapped it in an element and it applied it there.

```js
var communityImages = document.querySelectorAll('img[src*="communityphoto_"]');
if( communityImages.length > 0 ){
  communityImages.forEach(function(image){
    image.outerHTML = '<div class="community-image">'+ image.outerHTML +'</div>';
  });
}
```

```css
.community-image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.community-image:after {
  content: "Photo submitted by the community, submit yours to our email";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://xhynk.com/placeholder/300/100/communityphoto_1/"/>
  <img src="https://xhynk.com/placeholder/300/100/communityphoto_2/"/>
  <img src="https://xhynk.com/placeholder/300/100/something/" />
  <img src="https://xhynk.com/placeholder/300/100/communityphoto_3/"/>
  <img src="https://xhynk.com/placeholder/300/100/communityphoto_4/"/>
  <img src="https://xhynk.com/placeholder/300/100/another/"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an absolutely genius solution! I was not aware that JS could achieve that, finding and wrapping the detected images in a class. It's perfect, and I just implemented it. thank you Xhynk, sent you a coffee!